# change of e-mail address to new e-mail

Tags: email

How to change my e-mail address for my ubuntu account? Current e-mail account has been closed, so cannot access it anymore. Need to change to new e-mail address. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're actually asking, ie. are you asking how you change your Ubuntu ONE SSO email account (ie. *the email I use to access sites like this using my Ubuntu account, which includes my @ubuntu.com email too*), OR the email that will display for my actual local systems' user, or something else. You'll have to be specific (*the two I mentioned differ greatly, as the first is done on launchpad online, the second via local settings etc*)

Comment: Some info on SSO. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230004 and https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2436504 If further issues in forum, you can post in Forum Feedback & Help. https://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=48 Please read the "sticky" theads for more info.